# Problems with VirtualHosts

Tags: centos, virtualhost, apache

Hello I am try set up a CentOS based web server currently and am having trouble getting the domains to work.

I set up the httpd.conf as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin alexgatti@msn.com
  DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/www/alexandergatti.com
  ServerName alexandergatti.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access the website the web browser says the server can't be found.  I contacted my host and they said the DNS was set up corrently.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you point your domain name "alexandergatti.com" to your public ip address and do port forwarding. If you didn't point it you must point it by going to the DNS Manager zone in your domains registrant EX: Go Daddy or 1and1 and point the sites ip address to your public ip.

Next if you didn't already do this. Port Forwarding is also most important. OK so now your visitors are at your ip but your router doesn't know where to send them. So lots of routers either have them in applications and gamig or access or Virtual Server. You open it and where it says port start or public do the public port. I prefer 80 because your visitors will not have to write domain.com:8080. they just type domain.com. Ending port or private port is the ip address you set for apache. Im assuming you chose 80. So there you type 80. At the ip address or points to   you type your computers private local ip which in my case is 192.168.1.205.....  Click add or update or save and try your site name again. If you try it from behind your router it might not work so try it on a phone that has web in your plan or at a neighbors internet. It should work.

Also at NameVirtualHost *:80 and VirtualHost *:80 you should put your public ip instead of the star or astreics..

So it should be looking like

```
NameVirtualHost my.ip.add.ress:80

<VirtualHost my.ip.add.ress:80>
  ServerAdmin alexgatti@msn.com
  DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/www/alexandergatti.com
  ServerName alexandergatti.com
</VirtualHost>
```